# Decode JWT Token using pyJWT

Tags: python, jwt

I am using jwt.decode() to decode an JWT token. But today when I am using

```
jwt.decode(IdToken, verify= False)
```

an error is coming

> It is required that you pass in a value for the "algorithms" argument when calling decode().

I dont want to validate the token, I simply just need to decode it.

Comment: You are not giving us much to work with here. Can you show some code? You are saying "But today" - what changed since yesterday?

Comment: There was a version update and the old `verify` paramter is no longer supported. The linked Q/A shows the update.

Comment: yes thank you i am using option parameter ryt now

Comment: I don't see how that other thread has the answer to this question. Mods?

Comment: @maxpaj: the accepted answer in the linked Q/A mentions the different ways to call `decode` in Version <2.0 and >= 2.0. That caused the problem for the OP.